# Sharing Google Apps Script Failure Notifications with my team

Tags: google-apps-script, triggers

I've built a trigger to run daily a spreadsheet and I would like not to be the only one receiving the "Summary of failures" email when the execution fails. Is it possible to add a different email address than the person that created the trigger? Thanks

[image]

Comment: [Set up a Gmail filter](https://support.google.com/mail/answer/6579?hl=en) to forward the failure notifications to another address.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the question:

> Is it possible to add a different email address than the person that created the trigger?

No.

One option, among many others, is to add a way to catch errors in the function called by the time-driven trigger and in case of an error send a custom email message to the team.

I.E. you could use `try...catch` and `MailApp.sendEmail(message)`

Reference

- https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/installable